R: Conditional suppression of values across multiple rows
This question is similar to this question, but the difference in this case is to suppress data row-wise.  The suppression is done in each row by replacing any value less than 6 in each row with -1 such that if in a row, there is only one suppressed value, I want to also suppress the next higher value in that row even though the value is higher than 5. In the case where no value is higher than 6, the values remain the same. I prefer solutions in dplyr because I am working with dataframe.
My Dummy data is:
df <- data.frame(list(w = c(7, 25, 9, 50), x = c(1, 25, 9, 50), y = c(6, 35, 1, 6), z = c(4,50, 1, 1)))

Expected output is:
   w  x  y  z
1  7  -1  6  -1
2 25 25 35 50
3  9  9  -1  -1
4 50 50  -1  -1

This is my attempt:
 df |> 
pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
     names_to = 'col',
     values_to = 'val') |> 
     group_by(col) |> 
     group_map(~.x) |> 
     map(\ (x)
         
         if(sum(x$val < 6) == 1){
              x |> 
              mutate(val = replace(val, val %in% sort(unique(val), partial = 2)[1:2], -1))
         }else{
              x |>
                   mutate(val = replace(val, val < 6, -1))
         }) |> 
     list_rbind(names_to = "col") |> 
       pivot_wider(names_from = col,
                 values_from = val)

but this does not seem to work. I any help will be appreciated.

One tidyverse option could be:
df %>%
 mutate(pmap_dfr(across(everything()), 
                 ~ ifelse((c(...) < 6) | (sum(c(...) < 6) == 1 & dense_rank(c(...)) <= 2), 
                          -1, 
                          c(...))))

   w  x  y  z
1  7 -1  6 -1
2 25 25 35 50
3  9  9 -1 -1
4 50 50 -1 -1


Using replace with the given conditions
library(dplyr)

val <- 6

df %>% 
  mutate(if_else(rowSums(. < val) == 1, 
                 replace(., . == apply(pmax(., val), 1, \(x) 
                                   min(sort(x))) | . < val, -1), 
                 replace(., . < val, -1)))
   w  x  y  z
1  7 -1  6 -1
2 25 25 35 50
3  9  9 -1 -1
4 50 50 -1 -1


@tmfmnk I read the requirements wrong. Should work now with the next higher value. Thanks for pointing that out!

Seems like a good case for apply()
# Work one row vector at a time
apply(df, 1, \(x) {
  
  # Suppress values
  x <- ifelse(x < 6, -1, x)
  
  # If only one suppressed, suppress the second-most min value
  if (sum(x %in% -1) == 1) {
    minval <- min(x[!(x %in% min(x))])
    x[which(x %in% minval)] <- -1
  }

  x
}) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame()

#>    w  x  y  z
#> 1  7 -1  6 -1
#> 2 25 25 35 50
#> 3  9  9 -1 -1
#> 4 50 50 -1 -1

